# How to send ICMP message through a specific network interface in Go?

Tags: go, networking, ping, icmp, network-interface

I am new to Go. I am trying to write a program that pings `8.8.8.8` but via a specific network interface (e.g. `eth0`). With the `ping` command on Linux, you can specify the `-I` flag to have the ICMP message sent through a specific network interface.

```
ping -I enp4s0 8.8.8.8
```

How can I do this with Go? I have looked at several packages - [`github.com/sparrc/go-ping`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sparrc/go-ping), [`github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping), and [`golang.org/x/net/icmp`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/icmp); none of them seem to let me set the interface.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `net.DialTCP` or `net.DialIP` if each interface has a distinct IP address, they'll return to you a connection using that interface. You can then manually send the ping yourself.

You could also use the `exec` package https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/ to send the `ping` on the network interface. You can use `exec` to interact with the shell and just pipe the output back into a buffer and read it.

Comment: `exec` is a good suggestion. But I would like to have the program work regardless if the `ping` command is available on the host system. I will check out `net.DialTCP` and `net.DialIP`, thanks!

Comment: @dayuloli what do you mean by "work regardless"? If the `exec` command returns an error you can just check the output in the buffer and respond accordingly.

Comment: Linux determines the device to send from during routing, dialing from a specific IP won't change the routing decision.

Comment: @InfinityCounter On Ubuntu, the `ping` command is provided by the `iputils-ping` package. This package can be removed. Other distributions may not include a `ping` command. So using `exec` relies on the `ping` command being available on the host machine. I would avoid that if possible.